# Understanding deferred procedure call (DPC)

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, interrupt, irq

I am reading OS and CPU concepts for writing device driver and i came across "deferred procedure call (DPC)" and how kernel interacts with DPC and IRQL. I really appreciate a simple explanation of what it is and when it is used?

I have read the official microsoft document and some other resources but i get more confused.

These are some of my resources:

[What Are Deferred Procedure Calls?](https://itstillworks.com/13653499/what-are-deferred-procedure-calls)

[Introduction to DPCs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/introduction-to-dpcs)

[Windows Internals](https://books.google.com/books?id=WZdCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=dpc%20windows%20internal&source=bl&ots=njmQDeeeuc&sig=ACfU3U1QTXqkHxk7MEthfsIUbWp8Sr0Dgg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimu6_08_foAhVnc98KHeysBQcQ6AEwDXoECGIQKQ#v=onepage&q=dpc%20windows%20internal&f=false)

Comment: "I have read the official microsoft document and some other resources but i get more confused." - What **exactly** confused you while you read these resources? You write that you want a *simple* explanation but don't specify what is difficult for you in existing explanations. Note, that Stack Overflow is a Question/Answers site for **specific** problems. We don't write books, articles which covers a large area of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look for irql definitions like this answers I think they are quite simple as well, Hope it help:

[What is irql?](https://superuser.com/a/1310858)

[Why irql is important?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/what-is-irql-and-why-is-it-important/ba-p/372666)

Comment: Non of these exactly define the "DPC". However it is useful for the "When it is used?" part.